# Does squaring a directed random graph more than double its out-degree?

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

As far as I know, it is [an unsolved question](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~hochberg/undopen/graphtheory/graphtheory.html)
whether or not this is true:

> If $G$ is <strike>a directed</strike> an oriented graph, $G^2$ always has some node whose outdegree is at least
>   double that of its outdegree in $G$.

For example, below vertex $10$ has outdegree $3$ in $G$ and $5$ in $G^2$.
The maximum outdegree-ratio increase of $3.5$ is achieved by vertex $15$,
which has outdegree $2$ in $G$ and $7$ in $G^2$.
Of course there are also vertices, such as $2$ in $G$, that have zero-outdegree,
and so their outdegree trivially doubles and satisfies the above hypothesis.

---

[image: GdirSq15]

          

<sup>A directed graph $G$ on $n=15$ nodes; and $G^2$.</sup>

---

My question is:

> ***Q***.
>   Is the expected maximum (finite) outdegree increase from $G$ to $G^2$ known
>   to grow logarithmically in $n$, for random directed
>   graphs generated by including each of the $2\binom{n}{2}$ directed edges
>   with fixed probability $p$?

Simulations suggest this may be true:

---

[image: SqDirGraph]

          

<sup>The maximum (finite) outdegree ratio increase, for $n$-node random graphs,
each edge included with probability 3%.</sup>


          

<sup>Each point is an average of $5$ simulations.
The illustrated curve is logarithmic.</sup>

---

Comment: The link refers to oriented graphs, not directed graphs, and also implies that multiple edges are suppressed in forming $G^2$.  Is that true for you too?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Good point. I used directed random graphs with no loops or multiple edges for $G$, but allowed $G^2$ to be whatever was dictated by squaring.

Comment: On your second question, for fixed $p$ asymptotically $G^2$ is a complete graph. To make the question interesting you need to have $p$ decrease as $n$ increases.  But it still looks like a pretty standard random graph problem.

Comment: [**The number of Seymour vertices in random tournaments and digraphs**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04061)
Maybe this is useful?